# How to apply coalesce to a matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I know I can coalesce three vectors in this way:

```
y <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, 5)
z <- c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 6)
k <- c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 8)
coalesce(y,z,k)
```

However, in real data, I only get the whole dataset like:

```
d <- rbind(y,z,k)
```

And in real life every time `d` has different row length (sometimes 3 rows, sometimes 4 rows) which means we cannot just write:

```
coalesce(d[1,],d[2,],d[3,])
```

I have thought about `split` function:

```
split(t(d),rep(1:nrow(d),each = ncol(d)))
```

And got:

```
$`1`
[1]  1 NA NA NA  5

$`2`
[1] NA NA  3  4  6

$`3`
[1] NA  1 NA NA  8
```

But the results by `split` function cannot be applied to coalesce function.

Is there a way to realize my thoughts?

Comment: What about `c(y, z, k)`

Comment: @Oliver Unfortunately I cannot. In real dataset I only get `d`, some `d`s might have `c(y,z,k,l)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it within `do.call()`, i.e.

```
do.call(coalesce, as.data.frame(t(d)))
#[1] 1 1 3 4 5
```